# Jquery each navigation order, undefined error

Tags: jquery, html, each

I want to segregate my navigation with jQuery, but each returns undefined for some elements in loop,
It looks like this:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="100">
    <a href="#" data-next="105">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="100">Prev</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="101">
    <a href="#" data-next="101">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="104">Prev</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="102">
    <a href="#" data-next="102">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="106">Prev</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="103">
    <a href="#" data-next="103">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="100">Prev</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="104">
    <a href="#" data-next="105">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="104">Prev</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="105">
    <a href="#" data-next="101">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="106">Prev</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This should look like this, first element gets prev id from last element, next element get next id from next element in list.

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="100">
    <a href="#" data-next="101">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="105">Prev</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="101">
    <a href="#" data-next="102">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="100">Prev</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="102">
    <a href="#" data-next="103">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="101">Prev</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="103">
    <a href="#" data-next="104">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="102">Prev</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="104">
    <a href="#" data-next="105">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="103">Prev</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="105">
    <a href="#" data-next="100">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="104">Prev</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/z0uyfmx6

Console:

```
101next
undefinedprev
undefinednext
100prev
103next
undefinedprev
undefinednext
102prev
105next
undefinedprev
undefinednext
104prev
```

Comment: kindly include js from fiddle

Comment: Before console code, there is a link.

Comment: Because `next/prev` will look for sibling elements

Comment: what should be the output according to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `next/prev` methods will look only for previous/next sibling elements. So in each `ul`, the first `li` won't have a previous and last one a next sibling element so those will print `undefined`.

Instead you can have a index based lookup like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var pList = $('.list-item');
  pList.each(function(i, e) {
    var index = pList.index(this);
    var next = pList.eq(index + 1).attr('data-post-id');
    var prev = index == 0 ? undefined : pList.eq(index - 1).attr('data-post-id');

    snippet.log(prev + ':' + $(this).attr('data-post-id') + ':' + next)

  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="100">
    <a href="#" data-next="105">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="100">Prev</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="101">
    <a href="#" data-next="101">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="104">Prev</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="102">
    <a href="#" data-next="102">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="106">Prev</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="103">
    <a href="#" data-next="103">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="100">Prev</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="104">
    <a href="#" data-next="105">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="104">Prev</a>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" data-post-id="105">
    <a href="#" data-next="101">Next</a>
    <a href="#" data-prev="106">Prev</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```